# How to scale a sprite proportionally by one axis - swift/spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game that requires a sprite to be resized by either an X value or Y value depending on the sprite size. How can I resize a sprite by either an X value or Y value yet have it scale proportionally? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proportional just means percentage,  so for example if you want to scale 10% on x, then you do `node.xScale += node.xScale * 0.1`

If you want to scale proportionally based on the original size only, then you just need to preserve the original scale somehow

```
let dScaleX = node.xScale * 0.1
...
node.xScale += dScale
```

Comment: Be sure to mark it as the answer if it is indeed what you were looking for